# Imported CacheModule from @nestjs/cache-manager saying undefined

Tags: nestjs

I have updated my nest version 9 to 10 and trying to import cache manager from cache manager package which is separate package at version 10. when i am trying to call CacheModule.registerAsync it says Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'registerAsync')[image]

I am trying get a solution.

Comment: can you give us minimum production code ?